# Is there is any way to open specific links from a website in multiple tabs but don't load any of them until I select the tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, tabs

In chrome I want to open specific links in different tabs directly from the website but don't load (as some sites like youtube auto load videos that can increase cpu, gpu and ram load) those links until I go to the specific tab(mean select one tab).

If you want to understand exactly what I mean, see this [example](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-multiple-urls/oifijhaokejakekmnjmphonojcfkpbbh) extension called “Open Multiple URLs” (in this you can open multiple links on multiple tabs but it doesn't load those tab until selected)

Is there's any way top do this?

Comment: Any and every time I open a link, it opens the page. It has always been thus.

Comment: yeah @john altho you can see in the example extension it can be achieved I guess

Comment: Edit the question with more specific requirements, e.g. "I want to do it in one click" or whatever you exactly need, instead of writing that you know something in a comment for an answer. Plus if you know about that possibility then you should mention it as something that you tried and that didn't quite work for you... How are we supposed to know that?

Comment: @Destroy666 mate I did say "directly from website" in my original question... but I slightly edited it so people can understand better I hope

Comment: Directly from website can mean lots of things. If you click extensions in the top bar and use their popups you're still on the website, but you need to do few clicks more. You should be as precise with your questions as possible and explain how you'd like it to work.

Answer (score 0):

So after poking with it for some time I found a solution that meets my need perfectly.

I've used this [Work Offline](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/work-offline/gcjdagaoojgeilcobhibkgbodajcojda) extension. And I used [shortcut](https://i.imgur.com/kNpIvRG.png) like here to enable this and now it works like a charm as I wanted, [here's](https://i.imgur.com/42Y13PU.mp4) it on action. You can toggle between the mode with a simple shortcut and also it doesn't load existing offline tabs even you toggle between online and offline on else where.

Keep in mind that you have to press option+z twice if you want only one specific tab online. Also you could pin the extension so that you can see the mode changing colour.